# Find and count duplicate records in SQL & order by maximum of count

Tags: php, mysql, sql, optimization, inner-join

I have two tables like this:

*first TableName : **votes***

```
|   type   |     item_id     |   user_id   |
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
|   like    |       45       |    james    |
|   like    |       45       |    George   |
|  dislike  |       32       |     Paul    |
```

*second TableName : **items***

```
|    item_id     | item_name |
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
|       32       |     USB   |
|       45       |     TV    |
|       57       |     Game  |
```

I want to show the items in order, depending on the amounts votes they have.
Something like this :

```
 TV    - >   2
 USB   - >   1
 Game  - >   0
```

I try something like this :

```
SELECT items.item_name
FROM items INNER JOIN (
    SELECT item_id,COUNT(item_id) as vote
    FROM votes 
    HAVING COUNT(item_id) > 1
    ORDER BY COUNT(item_id) DESC
) AS votes ON votes.item_id= items.item_id 
WHERE items.item_id= 'item_id'
```

But nothing. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT `items`.`item_name`, IFNULL(COUNT(`votes`.`item_id`),0) AS `voting` FROM `votes`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `items` ON `items`.`item_id` = `votes`.`item_id`
GROUP BY `items`.`item_id`
ORDER BY `voting` DESC;
```

Comment: Good answer. For +1s, can you explain the main features of it? For example, what does `IFNULL()` do?

Comment: The Left Outer Join is going to produce Null against the items that do not have any Votes. So the IFNULL makes sure that if a null value is produced it outputs it as a 0.

Answer (score 1):

You had a couple of issues with your query.  First, you have a `where` clause that is not needed, and is likely to filter everything out.  Second, you have a `having` clause that also filters out items.

If you want to get all items, ordered by the number of votes, you also need a `left outer join`, because some items may not have votes:

```
SELECT items.item_name
FROM items LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT item_id, COUNT(item_id) as vote
      FROM votes 
      HAVING COUNT(item_id) > 1
      ORDER BY COUNT(item_id) DESC
     ) AS votes
    ON votes.item_id = items.item_id
ORDER BY coalesce(votes.vote, 0) desc;
```

And, finally, you say "votes", not distinguishing between likes and dislikes.  I assume this is intentional.

Comment: Here the SELECT in parenthesis outputs only one record. Thanks you for your help !!! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using a GROUP BY will allow you to use aggregate functions on the joined in table data without the need for a subquery.

```
SELECT items.item_name, COUNT(votes.item_id) as count
FROM items LEFT JOIN votes on items.item_id = votes.item_id
GROUP BY items.item_id
ORDER BY count DESC
```

Comment: And this works in phpMyAdmin in SQL test but not in my website :/

Comment: The answer you accepted is a copy of this so it should work just the same.  The only difference is that they added an unnecessary IFNULL function in.

Comment: Actually, in their query the IFNULL is required as they are using an outer join.  We're using an inner join so it's not necessary.